# customizing registration fields for new users in phpbb3

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

i am new to phpbb. i have a requirement where i need to remove some fields from registration page.(Some are mandatory and some are not). Can anybody please suggest where should i edit in file. i already changed in HTML file `styles/themename/templets/ucp_register_original.html` . but nothing is affecting the main interface.

```
<tr>
    <td class="row1"><b class="genmed">{L_LANGUAGE}: </b></td>
    <td class="row2"><select name="lang" onchange="change_language(this.value); return false;">{S_LANG_OPTIONS}</select></td>
</tr>
```

i have disable this for example but it is still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the answer given by Damien Keitel. one more and crucial thing you have to do is to delete `cache/tpl_prosilver-se_ucp_register.html.php` otherwise it will keep on showing the previous fields which you might have deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much:) i was banging my head for the last 6 hours. why it is not showing changes.

Comment: I always assumed purging the cache from the general tab was done, my mistake. Well picked up Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

**open**

> ```
> your_phpbb_root_directory/includes/ucp/ucp_register.php
> ```

**then find any of these**

```
'S_LANG_OPTIONS'    => (sizeof($lang_row) > 1) ? language_select($user_lang) : '',
```

**and replace with this**

```
'S_LANG_OPTIONS'    => '',
```